# Squarespace Dev Mode - Will I lose my work if I turn on dev mode?

Tags: squarespace

I've set up a squarespace site using the easy, drag and drop editor. I have been editing a template, creating each section as I went.

Now I need to turn on dev mode so I can make some tweaks to the way the main nav is laid out within the template files.

If I turn on dev mode now, will I lose all the work I've already done in the easy, drag and drop editor?

Answer (score 0):

No. You retain all of the drag and drop interface goodness.